# Why the definition of homophily in two papers are almost contrast?

Tags: social-psychology, group

Homophily is the tendency of individuals to associate and bond with similar others.

[Murase, 2019](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40990-z) says that

Social tie formation includes **focal closure** and **cyclic closure**. The difference between these two is that focal closure is that the bond formed without a common friend while cyclic closure is formed with a common friend.

And they said that **focal closure is homophily**

> As said above the focal closure is considered being based on homophily
>
> The mechanism of focal closure, i.e., the process of forming links to
> others with shared characteristics but without common acquaintances
> can be considered as a typical manifestation of homophily

However, in another paper [Passe, 2018](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/10e064ae-6240-3314-9d2f-1c0a017bac72/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B33d76f1d-88d5-34a7-9540-a2544c48b2ec%7D) says that homophilic relationship is affected by organizational affiliation or family ties. So, it means that **homophily here is similar to cyclic closure rather than focal closure** as Murase, 2019 documented.

> Homophily is influenced by the structural components of geography,
> organizational affiliations, and family ties

I am wondering if I fall into any fallacy. Thanks in advance.